# Bower install failing on ElasticBeanstalk - cannot find GIT

Tags: git, bower, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy an app onto elastic beanstalk that uses bower to download some libraries. I am getting the following error on deployment:

```
ERROR: [Instance: i-b4b8893d] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: bower jquery.cookie#~1.4.1      ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH. 
container_command 04_bower_install in .ebextensions/01-flask.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

Here is my config file:

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: "app.py"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "static/"
packages:
  yum:
    libjpeg-turbo-devel: []
    libpng-devel: []
    freetype-devel: []
    git: []
commands:
  01_set_home:
    command: export HOME=/home/ec2-user
  02_get_sudo:
    command: echo Defaults:root \!requiretty >> /etc/sudoers 
  03_npm_install:
    command: sudo yum -y --enablerepo=epel install nodejs npm
  04_npm_install_bower:
    command: sudo npm install -g bower
container_commands:
  01_set_path:
    command: export PATH=$PATH
  02_set_home:
    command: export HOME=/home/ec2-user
  03_set_git:
    command: export ENOGIT=/usr/bin/git
    command: export GIT=/usr/bin/git
  04_bower_install:
    command: 'bower --allow-root install'
    env:
      HOME: /home/ec2-user
      ENOGIT: /usr/bin/git
      GIT: /usr/bin/git
```

From my googling, people have suggested making sure git is installed, so I added it to the packages > yum directive, making sure the PATH variable is exported, as well as the GIT variables. As you can see I have tried all of these and nothing fixes the error.

Any ideas?
Thanks
Max Mumford.

Comment: have you tried sshing into one of your instances to check that git is actually installed?

Comment: Yep, "which git" outputs /usr/bin/git

Comment: make sure your bower config uses the full path. the problem here is not with beanstalk but with whatever is trying to actually use git. It might not have the updated information about PATH which you put inside container_commands.

Comment: @MaxMumford did you find a solution?

Comment: @ibstr Nope, found a workaround in the end if I remember correctly...

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it with that:

```
  04_bower_update:
    command: "bower update --allow-root"
    env:
      "PATH": "/usr/bin"
```